# Connect Raspberry Pi to Ubuntu Laptop with Damaged ETHERNET PORT

Tags: wireless

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. Now, I want to connect Raspberry Pi module with this laptop. But the Ehternet Port of my Laptop is damaged. So, I want to connect via wi fi or via HDMI cable. Please show me the steps how can I do this.

I am new to Linux environment. Please tell me in detail.

Regards
Prof. Kalyan Chatterjee
University of Calcutta
India

Comment: HDMI cable is probably poor choice for data exchange. Perhaps you should expand your question to include USB?

Answer (score 3):

Connect the Pi directly to the router with ethernet cable and get the IP address from the connected device list. Now connect your laptop to the same network via WiFi and use SSH/VNC/RDP to access the Pi.

If you don't have access to the router, connect both devices to the same wifi network and use SSH/VNC/RDP to access the Raspberry Pi.

I don't know if Pi supports Ethernet over HDMI.

Comment: Actually in my laptop, the Ethernet hardware is damaged. The main problem I am facing is during the connection of the Pi module with Laptop.

Comment: @Kalyan Chatterjee, Is the wifi (alias wireless LAN) working in the laptop? Have you got a router (with wifi (and ethernet))?

Answer (score 1):

**Using SSH**

SSH allows you to connect from one computer to another through terminal. You can use it like this:

```
ssh username@address
```

So if the username is "pi" and the address is "192.168.48.2", I would use:

```
ssh pi@192.168.48.2
```

After you enter it in, you will be prompted for your password. Enter it in and you are now logged into your Raspberry Pi through ssh.

**Using Secure Copy**

If you want to only copy files, use this command:

```
scp /path/to/file username@address:/path/to/destination
```

This will copy a file from your computer to another computer.

If you want to copy a file from another computer to your's, use this:

```
scp username@address:/path/to/file /path/to/destination
```

**Using XRDP**

If you want to control it with remote desktop, you have to install xrdp on your pi. Install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Now you need a remote desktop client on your computer, I like to use remmina:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina
sudo apt-get install remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Open remmina and create a new connection. Select rdp as the protocol, enter in the ip address and select "Enable SSH Tunnel" in the SSH tab. Select security as "RDP" in the Advanced tab. Save it and connect. You should be able to get into your raspberry pi.

I'm not sure if USB works, but you can give it a try.

And as for HDMI, I wouldn't recommend it, too much trouble into getting it working.

Comment: In that case, I would require the IP address of the Pi module right? Can you tell me how can I get the IP address of the pi module?

Comment: @KalyanChatterjee Open a terminal window and type `ifconfig` Check under the wireless section. You should see an ipv4 address if it is connected to a network.